# Selenium - mobileEmulation not working after chromedriver version updation to 2.30

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Below code is working fine, when I use chromedriver ver 2.28 but giving me below error when I use Chromedriver ver 2.30

**Stack-trace:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot parse 
capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error:  cannot parse mobileEmulation
from unknown error: 'Google Nexus 5' must be a valid device
from unknown error:  must be a valid device
```

**Code:**

```
    String chromedriver = CONFIG.getProperty("chromedriverpath");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriver);

    Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");

    Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    chromeOptions.put("args", Arrays.asList("--disable-extensions",
            "no-sandbox", "--allow-running-insecure-content", "ignore-
     certificate-errors","disable-infobars"));

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that the device was renamed to "Nexus 5".

So either create a custom device or use one from the list present in dev tools:

- BlackBerry Z30
- Blackberry PlayBook
- Galaxy Note 3
- Galaxy Note II
- Galaxy S III
- Kindle Fire HDX
- LG Optimus L70
- Laptop with HiDPI screen
- Laptop with MDPI screen
- Laptop with touch
- Microsoft Lumia 550
- Microsoft Lumia 950
- Nexus 10
- Nexus 4
- Nexus 5
- Nexus 6
- Nexus 7
- Nokia Lumia 520
- Nokia N9
- iPad Mini
- iPhone 4
- Galaxy S5
- Nexus 5X
- Nexus 6P
- iPhone 5
- iPhone 6
- iPhone 6 Plus
- iPad

Comment: mobile emulation works for me only for the out of the box devices list in your answer, why does my custom devices are not working?